# Find the function the range of the $\frac{5+2\sqrt{3+2x}-x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}}$

Tags: functions

Find the function range 
$$f(x)=\dfrac{5+2\sqrt{3+2x}-x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{3-x}}$$

since
$$\begin{cases}
3+2x\ge 0\\
x+1\ge 0\\
3-x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
then the function domian is 
$-1\le x\le 3$

and $f(-1)=f(3)=4$,the computer say $2.98992\le f(x)\le 4$,what is $2.98992?$

Comment: We don't know where the minumin of the value,becasue  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(5%2B2sqrt(3%2B2x)-x)%2F(sqrt(x%2B1)%2Bsqrt(3-x)) , $f(x)\le 4$,when $x=-1$ or $x=3$

Comment: That's  with engine but if we are not allowed to use such tools we are unaware of both minima,maxima

Comment: To answer your specific question, 2.98992 is the value of $f(x)$ at $x=1.284983984755307...$. What is that value? Answer: it is the real root of a polynomial of degree 8 in the range $[-1,3]$ and is the value which minimises $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a nice question.

As you say, we have to find the minimum value of $f(x)$ in the range $-1\le x\le3$.

[image]

If we differentiate $f(x)$ and set it equal to 0 we get a fairly horrible expression. If we plot that we get:

[image]

After a good deal of algebra we find that the minimum value satisfies this 8th degree polynomial $$4x^8+52x^7+253x^6-146x^5-949x^4+3208x^3+7011x^2-7722x-6831$$

This has two real roots, but only one of them is in the range $[-1,3]$, namely $x=1.284983984755307\dots$. If we substitute back into the original equation we find $f(x)=2.9899207119021423\dots$. So the range of the function is from this value to 4.